# EF migration : Error changing an indexed field to nullable

Tags: entity-framework-5, entity-framework-migrations

The code in my initial migration was as follows

> ```
>         CreateTable(
>             "dbo.Sites",
>             c => new
>                 {
>                     Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
>                     Description = c.String(maxLength: 450)
>                 })
>             .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id);
> ```

So that the Description field would be unique I added the following to the end of the UP method

> CreateIndex("dbo.Sites", "Description", unique: true);

Later I decided to make the Description field required.

The new migration generates the following change

> AlterColumn("dbo.Sites", "Description", c => c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 450));

However when this change attempts to run I get an error

> ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN Description failed because one or more objects access this column.

I was able to isolate the SQL line using the profiler, as

> ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Sites] ALTER COLUMN [Description] nvarchar NOT NULL

Which gives me the following error when I run it in Management Studio

> Msg 5074, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   The index 'IX_Description' is dependent on column 'Description'.
>   Msg 4922, Level 16, State 9, Line 1
>   ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN Description failed because one or more objects access this column.

How can I get the migration code to drop the index, then change alter the column and then re-build the index ?

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2

Comment: Using unique index with nullable column is strange. Null is value as any other so only ONE record will be able to have Null value otherwise you will receive unique constraint violation.

Comment: I though NULL != NULL but don't think I've tried it myself recently - worth checking that.

Comment: I want blank to be a valid option in the combo box. Should I have Null or an empty string for that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Something like this perhaps?

```
DropIndex("dbo.Sites", "IX_Description");
AlterColumn("dbo.Sites", "Description", c => c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 450));
CreateIndex("dbo.Sites", "Description", unique: true);
```

I think you can also execute SQL direct as below.

```
Sql("DROP INDEX [IX_Description] ON [dbo].[Sites] WITH ( ONLINE = OFF )");
```

Which can be useful if you want to add a check the index exists or something.

Comment: Thanks, your answer works. However the SQL alternative fails if the index is not already present.

Comment: Yes you'd need to have an IF EXISTS statement if you wanted that robustness. Personally I'd generate the drop script from SQL management studio and paste that in as that normally includes that check.

Comment: i am not seeing the check when I generate from management studio. Am I doing it the right way? right click the index and script index Drop To... I do see a setting in the create script. DROP_EXISTING

Comment: `IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.indexes WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[Sites]') AND name = N'IX_Description') Drop Index [IX_Description] on [dbo].[Sites]`

Comment: Thanks for this. I wonder why it happened though? I looked through my other migrations and they had auto-generated `DropIndex`es where needed.

Comment: Entity Framework auto-generates migrations based on your Model classes, data annotations and Fluent API mappings. During auto-generation, it does not know about anything you have manually added to a migration, so it does not know that a DropIndex is required here. You cannot add the index via the Fluent API either. But if you'd like to be able to you'll find a link to vote for it here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18694276/150342 (as well as more information about indexes)