# Define a unique property in model with entity framework code fist

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, code-first

Is it possible in Entity Framework 5 to define a property as "Unique" besides the Key?

My Model already has a property "ID" which has the 'Key' attribute. Now I want another prperty to be unique. How can I achieve this?

Comment: check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8262590/entity-framework-code-first-fluent-api-adding-indexes-to-columns which lets you add a unique index. You can add a unicity constraint at the cost of adding an index.

Comment: In addition to the above it may be desirable to add the uniqueness check in your business logic for early checking and provide meaningful feedback before you get a Sql Exception.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot do that through EntityFramework, the only possibility is modifying your database.

It's in the pipeline however for EF 6: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/efdesign/archive/2011/03/09/unique-constraints-in-the-entity-framework.aspx

Comment: Yes, I already found out it is not "out of the box" but surely there has to be a workaround for it right?

Comment: Yes, by editing your database directly. Since there's no notion of it in EF, there's no way to specify it, not through the FluentAPI, nor with attributes, nor with mappings

Comment: Migrations allow to add a unique index without editing the db directly. But the result is basically the same - a unique db index and EF's model metadata have no knowledge about it. BTW: Unique constraints won't come with EF 6, it has been postponed again :(