# combination of two field must be unique in Entity Framework code first approach. how it would?

Tags: entity-framework

I have two class contacts and groups

Combination of `FirstName` and `LastName` must be unique and can add multiple addresses for a single contact. How I can done this in entity framework code first approach?

```
public class Contacts
{
    [Key]
    public int ContactID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Group")]
    public int GroupID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Address { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Number { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [EmailAddress]
    public string EmailId { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ModifiedDate { get; set; }

    public virtual Groups Group { get; set; }
}

public class Groups
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int GroupID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string GroupName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string GroupDiscription { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime ModifiedDate { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Checking for duplicates means you have to go to the database to validate. In Entity Framework Code First, that means using the DbContext. See [Implementing Validation in the Context with ValidateEntity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg193959.aspx) for a great explanation of how to validate in Entity Framework.

You should override the ValidateEntity method in your context class:

```
    protected override DbEntityValidationResult ValidateEntity(
                                        DbEntityEntry entityEntry, 
                                        IDictionary<object, object> items)
    {
        //base validation for Data Annotations, IValidatableObject
        var result = base.ValidateEntity(entityEntry, items);

        //You can choose to bail out before custom validation
        //if (result.IsValid)
        //    return result;

        CustomValidate(result);
        return result;
    }

    private void CustomValidate(DbEntityValidationResult result)
    {
        ValidateContacts(result);
        ValidateOrganisation(result);
    }

private void ValidateContacts(DbEntityValidationResult result)
{
    var c = result.Entry.Entity as Contact;
    if (c== null)
        return;

    if (Contacts.Any(a => a.FirstName == c.FirstName 
                          && a.LastName == c.LastName 
                          && a.ID != c.ID))
        result.ValidationErrors.Add(
                          new DbValidationError("Name", 
                                "Name already exists"));
}

private void ValidateOrganisation(DbEntityValidationResult result)
{
    var organisation = result.Entry.Entity as Organisation;
    if (organisation == null)
        return;

    if (Organisations.Any(o => o.Name == organisation.Name 
                               && o.ID != organisation.ID))
        result.ValidationErrors.Add(
                              new DbValidationError("Name", 
                                    "Name already exists"));
}
```

This validation is triggered when there is a call to `SaveChanges`. If there are any errors, a `DbEntityValidationException` is thrown.

More about structuring validation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16647237/150342)

For a "belt and braces" approach I also add unique indexes to the database on my natural keys - in a migration. Thus preventing invalid data because of inserts to the database that do not go via Entity Framework :

```
public partial class Adduniqueindexes : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        //You have to use Sql if the column is nullable:
        Sql(@"CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IX_UPRN ON Properties(UPRN, OrganisationID) 
            WHERE UPRN IS NOT NULL"));
        CreateIndex("dbo.Organisations", 
                    "Name", 
                     unique: true, 
                     name: "IX_NaturalKey");
        CreateIndex("dbo.Contacts", 
                    new string[] { "FirstName", "LastName" }, 
                    unique: true, 
                    name: "IX_NaturalKey");
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        DropIndex("dbo.Properties", "IX_UPRN");
        DropIndex("dbo.Organisations", "IX_NaturalKey");
        DropIndex("dbo.Contacts", "IX_NaturalKey");
    }
}
```

More about indexes [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18205124/150342)

**Additional note**
From EF6.1 onwards it is possible to indicate that an index should be created on a field by adding a data attribute:

```
[Index("IX_NaturalKey", IsUnique = true)]
[Required] //If the field is nullable then you have to create the index in the migration
           //using sql, so I'd only expect IsUnique = true on a Required field
[StringLength(256)] //indexes must be less than 900 bytes in Sql Server,
                    //so nvarchar(max) will not do
public string Name{ get; set; }
```

Comment: @Colin Is a unique index supposed to throw a validation error if a violating entity is added to the set, or is it just supposed to create an index in the database?

Comment: @ginkner the unique index will cause a database exception if invalid data is entered. But Entity Framework should throw a `DbEntityValidationException` before that. The unique index prevents invalid data getting into the database if you ever run sql via any other route and it should make the validation check faster. See the answer from @GertArnold too

Answer (score 1):

There is no magical support for this in Entity Framework. You'll have to do this manually. First check if the contact in one batch have unique names. Then check whether any `FirstName/LastName` combination exists in the database.

This is never going to be a robust solution though, because there will always be a latency between the check and the final commit to the database. So as an ultimate guard you really should add a unique database index on `FirstName/LastName`.