# Entity Framework KeyAttribute as ValidationAttribute

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, data-annotations

I'm using Entity Framework code-first and so I make liberal use of Data Annotations. I use the `[Key]` annotation, which is from `sealed class KeyAttribute` and noticed that it has no client-side validation as it inherits from the `Attribute` class and not the `ValidationAttribute` class.

Because the class is `sealed`, I can't inherit from it. Is there another way to add validation through data annotation without simply making another attribute that mimics `[Key]`?

(I'm attempting to avoid something like `[Key, KeyValidation("There may only be one!")]`)

Comment: What exactly do you need to validate? A primary key is unique. If it is an identity then you have nothing to validate.

Comment: I don't think that you should be letting your users/front-end interact with your primary keys in any way. This could cause a lot of issues. Can you explain why you are trying to do this?

Comment: @Chris Essentially I'd like to give a user full-control. I understand the risks, however that's kind of the idea behind the validation. A user wouldn't be able to commit changes to the actual database if their primary keys are highlighted red.

Comment: it seems Microsoft didn't think about if someone wants to give users the control of the unique/primary-key field. it seems you need your own custom one for this case.

Comment: How to check for duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18736484/150342