# Handle Concurrency with Transaction in Entity Framework while saving collection

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I would like to use the same dbContext to save a collection of Program type objects, but if there is any exception or concurrency exception in any of the program object, I would like to rollback the whole saved collection, and need to notify user about all program objects where concurrency issue occurred. I am using Entity Framework 6.1.

Find the code snippet. I am facing an issue that, if any of program object is having concurrency exception then programContext object is throwing the same exception again even if next record is not having any concurrency issue. Please guide on this if it is wrong then how can we achieve it in EF6.1

```
//Code
public List<ProgramViewModel> SavePrograms(List<ProgramViewModel> newAndUpdatedPrograms)
{
        List<ProgramViewModel> failedPrograms = new List<ProgramViewModel>();
        using (ProgramContext programContext = new ProgramContext())
        {
            using (DbContextTransaction dbProgramTransaction = programContext.Database.BeginTransaction())
            {
                bool isErrorOccured = false;
                foreach (var item in newAndUpdatedPrograms)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Program program = new Program();
                        program.ProgramID = item.ProgramId;
                        program.Title = item.Title;
                        program.ProgramCode = item.ProgramCode;
                        program.Description = item.Description;

                        //This is to check whether user is having the latest record or dirty record (Concurency check)
                        program.RowVersion = System.Convert.FromBase64String(item.RowVersion);

                        if (program.ProgramID == 0)
                            programContext.Entry(program).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Added;
                        else
                            programContext.Entry(program).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;

                        programContext.SaveChanges(); //Throws the previous concurrency exception here
                    }
                    catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException ex)
                    {
                        isErrorOccured = true;
                        failedPrograms.Add(item);
                    }
                }
                if (isErrorOccured)
                {
                    dbProgramTransaction.Rollback();
                }
                else
                {
                    dbProgramTransaction.Commit();
                }
            }
        }

        return failedPrograms;
    }
```

Comment: put the foreach inside the try/catch

Comment: More on concurrency here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27013719/150342