# Entity Framework - Handling PK/UKC 2601 violations for duplicate keys

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

At some point in the application, there's some heavy processing and a considerable graph with multiple different entitites is created in the dbcontext for insertion.
Consider the following entities, part of a bigger model:

```
public class Wall
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }

    public ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
}

public class Post
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Labels> Labels { get; set; }
}

public class Label
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Index("IX_UniqueNameKind", IsUnique = true, Order = 1)]
    [MaxLength(255)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Index("IX_UniqueNameKind", IsUnique = true, Order = 2)]
    [MaxLength(60)]
    public string Kind { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}
```

I have a many-to-many relationship between Post and Label with an assocation table "PostLabel" to avoid redundant db entries and optimize space usage. Each label uniquess is defined by "name" and "kind".

The problem occurs when multiple users could be running the same process and inserting the same label (name, kind), causing EntityFramework's SaveChanges to throw an DbUpdateException exception.

Currently, I'm detaching the "labels" which failed to be inserted and associating the existing "labels" from the db instead.

```
public override int SaveChanges()
{   
    while (!isSaved)
    {
        try
        {
            // save data
            result = base.SaveChanges();

            // set flag to exit loop
            isSaved = true;
        }
        catch (DbUpdateException ex)
        {
            var sqlException = ex.InnerException?.InnerException as SqlException;
            if (sqlException != null && sqlException.Errors.OfType<SqlError>().Any(se => se.Number == 2601 || se.Number == 2627) && ex.Entries.All(e => e.Entity.GetType() == typeof(Label))
            {
                // handle duplicates: find existing record in DB and associate it to the parent Post entity.
                var entries = ex.Entries;
                foreach (var entry in entries)
                {
                    HandleLabelDuplicates(entry);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
    }

    return result;
}

private void HandleSourceSegmentLabelDuplicates(DbEntityEntry entry)
{
    var labelWhichFailedToInsert = (Label)entry.Entity;
    var labelAlreadyInDatabase = Labels.Single(t => t.Name.Equals(labelWhichFailedToInsert.Name) && t.Kind.Equals(labelWhichFailedToInsert.Kind));

    // fix label association in all "Posts" which contain this label.
    foreach (var post in labelWhichFailedToInsert.Posts)
    {
        // fix the reference to the existing label in the database, instead of inserting a new one.
        post.Labels.Add(labelAlreadyInDatabase);
    }

    // change state to remove it from context
    entry.State = EntityState.Detached;
}
```

The problem here is that the whole DbContext is inserted multiple times, more precisely everytime an exception is handled plus 1, so if one duplicate is found, the whole model is inserted twice in the DB.

My guess is that at the first attempt to SaveChanges, all the entities inserted successfully don't get their state updated to "Unchanged" since an exception is thrown, however the insertions are in the SQL transaction, consequently, the 2nd attempt to SaveChanges will insert them again.

Any ideas?

EDIT:
The whole work is being done within a transaction:

```
        using (var transaction = context.Database.BeginTransaction())
        {
            // some work
            context.Orders.Add(order);
            context.SaveChanges();
            // some more work where some id's are needed
            context.SaveChanges();
            transaction.Commit();
            return order.Id;
        }
```

It appears that the problem is repeating SaveChanges() when handling exceptions/duplicates when wrapped within a transaction, if I unwrap everything from the transaction it works as it should.

Comment: What about to enclose savechanges into a transaction?

Comment: @daniherrera I've updated the question with the code which encloses the saveChanges into a transaction

Answer (score 0):

I see no `lock()` here, this could be one of the solutions you can consider. 
Lock the operation, wait for the update to complete and resume again.

Second, I see no `DbUpdateConcurrencyException` handling, so another solution you may consider is:

```
using (var context = new Ctx())
{
    //your logic
    while (!saved)
    {
        try
        {
            // Attempt to save changes to the database
            context.SaveChanges();
            saved = true;
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException ex)
        {
            foreach (var entry in ex.Entries)
            {
                if (entry.Entity is YourModel)
                {
                    var proposedValues = entry.CurrentValues;
                    var databaseValues = entry.GetDatabaseValues();

                    foreach (var property in proposedValues.Properties)
                    {
                        var proposedValue = proposedValues[property];
                        var databaseValue = databaseValues[property];

                        // TODO: decide which value should be written to database
                        // proposedValues[property] = <value to be saved>;
                    }

                    // Refresh original values to bypass next concurrency check
                    entry.OriginalValues.SetValues(databaseValues);
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new NotSupportedException(
                        "Don't know how to handle concurrency conflicts for "
                        + entry.Metadata.Name);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Notice the flexibility and versatility of the solution for the concurrency issue.

Comment: DpUpdateConcurrencyException is not thrown in my case.

Comment: Lock() it is then :)

Comment: Surely it would fix it :) However a lock() in SaveChanges() seems a bit too extreme to me, It's used all over the application since it's overriden.