# Prevent user from submitting a timesheet record twice in MVC C# and using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, datetime

I have a timesheet system written in ASP.NET MVC in C# with Entity Framework 6 and I want to prevent users from submitting overlapping / clashing timesheets for the same job.

The SQL Server `timesheet` table has a number of columns, these are the most relevant:

```
╔═══════════════╦══════════╗
║ Column Name   ║ DataType ║
╠═══════════════╬══════════╣
║ UserId        ║ int      ║
║ JobId         ║ int      ║
║ StartDateTime ║ datetime ║
║ EndDateTime   ║ datetime ║
╚═══════════════╩══════════╝
```

and here's a sample of data:

```
╔══════╦════════╦═══════╦══════════════════╦══════════════════╗
║  Id  ║ UserId ║ JobId ║  StartDateTime   ║   EndDateTime    ║
╠══════╬════════╬═══════╬══════════════════╬══════════════════╣
║ 4893 ║    245 ║   119 ║ 26/08/2014 17:00 ║ 27/08/2014 08:00 ║
╚══════╩════════╩═══════╩══════════════════╩══════════════════╝
```

What would be the most efficient way to prevent a clash of date/time if someone tries to submit an overlapping timesheet for the same `JobId`?

Thanks for any pointers on this, as I want to keep the system pretty fast - which it currently is but the timesheet table will eventually have many rows to traverse through.

Comment: Can a user have overlapping times of different jobs?

Comment: This type of validation needs to go to the database.The best place to do that is in the context class - a bit like checking for duplicates. But instead of an index, you will need a check constraint - http://stackoverflow.com/a/18736484/150342

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller, assuming the POST method is

```
public ActionResult Edit(List<TimeRecord> timeRecords);
{
  // Sort by start time and group by job number
  var jobRecords = timeRecords.OrderBy(r => r.StartDateTime).GroupBy(r => r.JobID);
  // enumerate each group
  foreach (var group in jobRecords)
  {
    // enumerate each record in the group
    foreach (var record in group)
    {
      if (group.Any(r => r != record && r.StartDateTime >= record.StartDateTime && r.StartDateTime < record.EndDateTime))
      {
        // we have overlapping records?
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @beebul. Forgot to exclude the current record in the `.Any()` statement (now updated). Did a few tests with 100 dummy records. Takes between 2 and 3 millisecond to complete if all valid (i.e. insignificant)

Comment: Sorry I can't get this to work, it throws an error even when the timesheet doesn't overlap.

Comment: Works fine for me (did you check my edit). What is the error?

Comment: Sorry, not an error, just that any entry gets flagged as an overlap even when it isn't..

Comment: I don't see how that's possible. You said that is valid to have overlapping times in different jobs - and this code allows that (e.g. `JobID=1, Start=8.00AM, End=9.00AM`, `JobID=1, Start=10.00AM, End=11.00AM`, `JobID=2, Start=8.00AM, End=9.00AM` is valid)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the SQL you need to see if there are any overlaps. I'll leave the conversion to EF as an exercise for the reader.

```
SELECT Count(*) 
FROM TimeEntry 
WHERE UserId = @UserId AND JobId = @JobId AND 
( 
    (StartDateTime < @StartDateTime AND @StartDateTime < EndDateTime)
OR
    (StartDateTime < @EndDateTime  AND @EndDateTime < EndDateTime)
OR
    (@StartDateTime <= StartDateTime AND EndDateTime <= @EndDateTime )
)
```