# Autogenerated string Primary Key in Entity Framwork

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Is there any way to make autogenerated primary keys for *string* type, **not** *int* or *guid*?

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)] //???
    public string Id { get; set; } // string type

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Login { get; set; }
}
```

In case of following questions "why?": the thing is that in my current model PK is login, and I want to imperceptibly separate login and primary key, saving PKs that's already in use.

Comment: Login - is that a user name? I predict that one day someone will say "we don't like auto-generated logins, can we create our own?" Or "can we use email addresses to login instead?" Then you're going to have to fix up all those foreign keys....

Comment: Exactly. At the moment the login IS the primary key. I want to make login as independent field, but save primary key as it is and generate PK for new users. Looks like manual generation is the only way.

Comment: I think I would make `Id` an integer with identity, fix up all those foreign keys that are currently strings - it's a pain, but you've got to do some sort of fix up anyway. Then I would treat `Login` as the "natural" key, and validate as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18736484/150342

Answer (score 1):

Identities for string column types are not supported with SQL Server. How do you expect a custom key string to look like?
You can do your key with Guid type and then fetch to string:

```
guid.ToString();
```