# How to set a custom class as Unique into an Entity in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Working on a WPF project using entity Framework 6.

My custom class includes 2 fields that would need to be unique (on top of id).
One is a string type, the other one is a custom type.

The implementation of the entity class is s follows:

```
public partial class MyEntity
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(100)]
    [Index(IsUnique = true)]
    public string Name{ get; set; }

    [MaxLength(100)]
    [Index(IsUnique = true)]
    public MyClass myClass { get; set; }
...
}
```

Then, when I tray to add a new MyEntity via:

```
context.SaveChanges();
```

I get this exception:

```
  Message=Unable to create a constant value of type 'NS.MyClass '. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.
  Source=EntityFramework
```

NB: the other unique field (Name) does not generate the exception if I comment the attribute of the MyClass declaration.

Is there really no way to set a custom class as Unique into an entity??

Thx in advance.

Comment: Use the Id of the class instead of class

Comment: ..and look at how to validate for uniqueness here...http://stackoverflow.com/q/18714550/150342

Answer (score 0):

In Entity Framework 6 you have to do this by your self. check my soultion here: [Unique Key constraints for multiple columns in Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18889218/unique-key-constraints-for-multiple-columns-in-entity-framework/18896518#18896518)