# Defining a composite key and identity on the same table using EF Code First

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, code-first

Take the following C# code. I am attempting to create `ClassC` which has a composite key but also create an identity in there that can be used as a foreign key in another table `ClassD`. I'd rather use this foreign key instead of trying to map the composite key which seems a bit odd.

```
public class ClassA
{
    [Key]
    public int ClassAID { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ClassC> SomeClassCs { get; set; }
}

public class ClassB
{
    [Key]
    public int ClassBID { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ClassC> SomeClassCs { get; set; }
}

public class ClassC
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ClassCID { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order=0), ForeignKey("SomeA")]
    public int ClassAID { get; set; } //Foreign Keys combined as Primary Key

    [Key, Column(Order=1), ForeignKey("SomeB")]
    public int ClassBID { get; set; }

    public virtual ClassA SomeA { get; set; }
    public virtual ClassB SomeB { get; set; }

}

public class ClassD
{
    [Key]
    public int ClassDID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("SomeC")]
    public int ClassCID { get; set; }
    public virtual ClassC SomeC { get; set; }
}
```

On creating my migration I receive the following error:

> System.Data.Entity.Edm.EdmAssociationConstraint: : The number of
>   properties in the Dependent and Principal Roles in a relationship
>   constraint must be identical.

Anyone solved this, or am I approaching this incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "I'd rather use this foreign key instead of trying to map the composite
>   key which seems a bit odd"

You are talking about [Natural](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_key) vs [Surrogate keys](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrogate_key)

This is what I do:

1. Use identity (surrogate) keys on all my models
2. Validate the data by
   overriding ValidateEntity in the context class - [prevent duplicates
   in entity framework](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18736484/150342)
3. Add unique indexes to the natural keys -
   [create indexes in migrations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18205124/150342)

Entity Framework does not provide data annotation attributes for identifying properties that are natural keys or should have unique indexes - but if you look at the answers in the links I've provided you will see that some people create custom attributes for that purpose

Answer (score 0):

Foreign key of Dependent entity should contain all Primary keys of the Principal. You can read more about foreign key constraints on [TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179610.aspx).

You have two primary keys on `ClassC` so, you should have two foreign keys on `ClassD` for this relation. Or you can make `ClassCID` to be single primary key, then your mapping for `ClassD` foreign key will work. In any case - foreign key of dependent table should be exactly same as primary key in principal table.